# EJS rendering HTML

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I've got a simple blog app on Express and MongoDB, using EJS to render my data.

The problem I have is I want this to be styled like a paragraph:

```
<div class="show-post__content">

   <%= post.body %>

 </div>
```

The content of the post.body is: `'<p>Hello there, this is a new post.</p>'`

but it's rendering like this:

[image]

If the picture doesn't work, it's showing up with the brackets visible, rather than looking like an actual html p tag if that makes any sense...
Does anyone know how to get around this?

Many thanks,

Raph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it:

```
<div class="show-post__content">

   <%- post.body %>

 </div>
```

Is the answer.

Thanks if you had a look!

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I had the similar issue a week ago
Mission was to disable javascript. I did that with sanitizer.
I sanitized user info before inserting in MongoDB.
So recommend you to do that with `sanitize-html`  `striptags`.
Those packages are in npm you can download the package.
I hope you will solve the problem.

```
var striptags = require('striptags');    
    YourCollectionName.find({}, function (err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        //handle or throw error
      }

  // For all the documents, remove html tags and save
  obj.forEach(function(ob){
    ob.body= striptags(ob.body);
    ob.save();
  });
});
```