# How can I render html tags in an express and ejs blogging application?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a blogging application with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

In my `posts.js` controller I have:

```
exports.getSinglePost = (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Post.findById(id, function(err, post){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('singlepost', {
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                post: post
            });
        }
    });
};
```

The singlepost.ejs view has the code:

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/images/home-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
            <span class="subheading"><%= post.short_description %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <%= post.full_text %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine as long as the entry in the posts collection does not contain HTML tags:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e3063dbfa749d9229bab26f"), "title" : "Post One", "short_description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "full_text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."}
```

But when it *does* contain HTML tags:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e317594fa749d9229bab271"), "title" : "Post One", "short_description" : "Dolor sit amet.", "full_text" : "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>"}
```

the `singlepost` view renders HTML in the **browser**:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

In AngularJS the problem would be easely solved with `ng-bind-html`, but I'm **not** using AngularJS in this project.

So, how can I fix this bug in **EJS**?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407713/ejs-rendering-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by replacing `<%= post.full_text %>` with `<%- post.full_text %>` (`=`  with `-`).

The `singlepost` view now is like so:

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('assets/images/home-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
            <span class="subheading"><%= post.short_description %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <%- post.full_text %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code:

```
Post.findById(id).then(post=> res. render('singlepost', {post:post})). catch (err=>console.log(err));
```

Then you log any post property

Answer (score -1):

```
<p><%- post._id %></p>
```

I think you can do something like this instead of what you are currently doing. But doing it by directly rendering tags won't be possible.